# . when input is greater than 10 , the code is not showing right output . but for less than 10 , it runs perfect

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std ;

int main ( )
{
    int i , j , n , m ;
    string str , str1  ;
    
    getline (cin , str ) ;
    n = str.length( ) ;
    
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
    {
        if (str[i] >=65 && str[i] <=90) {
            str[i] = str[i] + 32 ;
        }
    }
    
    for (i=0 , j = 0; i<n   ; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' || str[i]== 'u')
        {
            continue ;
        }
        else {
            str1[j] = '.' ;
            str1[j+1] = str[i] ;
            j= j+ 2 ;
            m = j ;
        }
    }
    
    for (i=0 ; i < m ; i++) {
        cout << str1[i] ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

why I found garbage value when input is greater then 11 characters ? if less then 11 , it is behaving perfectly .
I basically want to remove all the vowel from the input and put dot before every consonant .

Codeforces ~ for this it runs well like below                                .c.d.f.r.c.s

But for this ~ ktajqhpqsvhw                                               it is showing ~  Exit code is 2147483647

Comment: It looks like you are accessing out-of-range of `str1`, which is a zero-length string.

Comment: not sure but short string optimization may be the cause for it appearing to work with smaller input

Comment: btw excessive use of whitespace and blank lines makes the code rather hard to read

Comment: What is the input and desired output? What this code supposed to do?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but [`std::to lower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) will do that case conversion without making hard-coded assumptions about the character encoding.

Comment: Buffer overflow: https://godbolt.org/z/4ssKGTKMP

Comment: I basically want to remove all the vowel from the input and put dot before every consonant and if there is any uppercase character ,, I want to make them lower case ..

Comment: No need for further debugging details. It is quite clear where the bug is... why the question is closed?

Comment: @AshikulIslam *I basically want to remove all the vowel from the input and put dot before every consonant .* -- Well, to be honest, this is a 4 or 5 line C++ program if you were to use `std::remove_if`, and other STL algorithm functions.

Comment: Fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/84P9ox6hW I'm still not aware what it suppose to do (doesn't seems right).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/nb767a1qv

Comment: I know I have to learn more STL , but here I am very new in this line . Can you find where the bug in this code .

Comment: Yes, easy! But the question is closed so nobody can answer. No idea why it was closed... sometimes there is some mystery here...

Comment: @AshikulIslam Change this: `str1[j] = '.' ;` to this `str1.at(j) = '.' ;`.  Then you will be greeted with a `std::out_of_range` exception.  And doing this, it will *not* run "well" for that "working" input under CodeForces (assuming they use g++) or any other C++ compiler.

Comment: @AshikulIslam FYI, a [quick and dirty example using STL](https://godbolt.org/z/KMTjhseqK).

Comment: @AshikulIslam I already wrote `buffer overflow` and link provided points exactly where error is. Basically you do not resize `str1`.

Comment: Marek is correct. google `buffer overflow`. As soon as you add more `.`s than you remove `vowel`s, it crashes. google `c++ resize string`.

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty string (str1) here

```
 string str , str1  ;
```

you then try to write to locations in it

```
  str1[j] = '.' ;
```

You cannot do that, me guess is that you want str1 to be the same size as str

```
  string str1 = string(" ",str.length());
```

That will create a string of spaces with the same size as str.

Or you can do

```
 str1.push_back('.')
```

This will increase the size of the string and add that character at the end